# How to use one submit button from the unput tag and not the button tag

Tags: html, forms, button, label, submit

```
  <label>Please enter your name</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="user0name"> <br>
  <button type="button" id="userbutton"></button>
  <input onclick="window.location.href = 'profile.html';" type="submit" value="submit" />
```

I tried to remove the value of the submit button on the button tag but this still here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpHYk.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

This will let your inpur box be clickable:

```
<input type="text" id="user0name" onclick="window.location.href = 'profile.html';" type="submit" value="submit"> <br>
```